# How to delete nodes in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm having trouble deleting nodes in a doubly linked list, the program crash and i can't figure out the problem. Can you please help me? 
This is the full code that creates new nodes, views them and deletes them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Test
{
  int id;
};

typedef struct Node {
  struct Test structure;
  struct Node * next;
  struct Node *prev;

}TNode;
typedef TNode* Node;

void NewNode(struct Test  p, Node *pp)
{
  Node temp;

  temp = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  temp->structure = p;
  temp->next = *pp;
  temp->prev = NULL;

  if(*pp != NULL)
  {
    (*pp)->prev = temp;
  }

  *pp = temp;

}

void ReadStructure(struct Test * p)
{
  printf("\nID:");
  scanf(" %d", &p->id);
}

void ViewList(Node node)
{
  Node temp;
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    temp = node->prev;
    if(node->prev == NULL)
      {
        printf("Prev = NULL\n");
      }
    else
    {
    printf("Prev: %d\n", temp->structure.id);
    }
    printf("Curr: %d\n", node->structure.id);
    node = node->next;
  }
}

void Delete(Node * head, Node del)
{

       if(*head == NULL || del == NULL)
        {
          return;
        }
       if(*head == del)
       {
         *head = del->next;
       }
       if(del->next != NULL)
       {
         del->next->prev = del->prev;
       }
       if(del->prev != NULL)
       {
         del->prev->next = del->next;
       }
       free(del);
       return;

}

int Menu()
{
  int c;

  printf("*** M E N U ***\n"
     "1 - New Node\n"
     "2 - View List\n"
   "3 - Delete\n"
   "0 - Exit\n"
  "\n>> ");
  scanf(" %d", &c);

  return c;
}

int main()
{
  int c;
  struct Test test;
  Node list = NULL;
  Node del = NULL;
  do {
    c = Menu();

    switch (c)
    {
      case 1: ReadStructure(&test);
              NewNode(test, &list); break;
      case 2: ViewList(list); break;
      case 3: printf("\nElement to Delete: ");
              scanf("%d", &del->structure.id);
              Delete(&list, del); break;
      default: c = 0;
    }

  } while (c != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is related to the scanf() for the Node del, but i'm not sure. When i just pass `list` or `list->next` as second argument to the function Delete() it works. Is everything all right with the code?

Comment: Run the program with gdb, and get a backtrace. Make sure you compile with debugging(`-g` on gcc). This will tell you exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: I did the debugging, when i type the element to delete and press enter, i get segmentation fault

Comment: I couldn't figure out where it crashes, i just typed run in gdb

Comment: It's `run` then on crash you type `bt`. The top most line shows you where it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
  ...
  Node del = NULL;
  ...
  scanf("%d", &del->structure.id);
```

Your program should crash here. You are dereferencing a null pointer.

Probably you will need to read the user input into a temporary `id` variable, then search the list for a matching item, and if you find one, then you can try deleting it.

Comment: I tried to not set the pointer to NULL and it errors that too. I will try your method and see if it helps.

Comment: BTW, it changes the alghorithm, so you're answer is a bit incomplete, i learned the original from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-node-in-a-doubly-linked-list/

Comment: Changes the algorithm? What do you mean? You cannot delete an entry without knowing where it is in the list. And that means you need to search for it. The alternative would be for the user to input the number 2 and for you to remove the second item in the list.... now **that** would be a change in the algorithm

Comment: In the geeksforgeeks alghorithm they pass a node to the function Delete. And to remove the current node they use the same pointer. 
It just do comparison between the structures of the two nodes.

Comment: The point is, they pass a **valid** pointer -- a pointer to an actual node that is in the list. I agree that if you just want to test the functionality of the remove function you can pass any node.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to be able to delete just the first node in the list, or any node. If you want to be able to delete any node.... how will you choose a node? It looks like you're asking the user to enter an id... ... ... so surely you want to delete the node that contains that id value? No?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i added a function that searches for the node to be deleted and i modified a bit the Delete() function, this is the workaround, thank you for the suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Test
{
  int id;
};

typedef struct Node {
  struct Test structure;
  struct Node * next;
  struct Node *prev;

}TNode;
typedef TNode* Node;

void NewNode(struct Test  p, Node *pp)
{
  Node temp;

  temp = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  temp->structure = p;
  temp->next = *pp;
  temp->prev = NULL;

  if(*pp != NULL)
  {
    (*pp)->prev = temp;
  }

  *pp = temp;

}

void ReadStructure(struct Test * p)
{
  printf("\nID:");
  scanf(" %d", &p->id);
}

void ViewList(Node node)
{
  Node temp;
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    temp = node->prev;
    if(node->prev == NULL)
      {
        printf("Prev = NULL\n");
      }
    else
    {
    printf("Prev: %d\n", temp->structure.id);
    }
    printf("Curr: %d\n", node->structure.id);
    node = node->next;
  }
}

Node SearchNode(Node head)
{
  int d;
  printf("\nElement to Delete:");
  scanf("%d", &d);

  while(head != NULL)
    {
      if(head->structure.id == d)
        {
          return head;
        }
      head = head->next;
    }
  printf("\nNo Element [%d] Found", d);
  return NULL;
}

void Delete(Node * head, struct Test temp)
{
  Node del = SearchNode(*head);

       if(*head == NULL || del == NULL)
        {
          return;
        }
       if(*head == del)
       {
         *head = del->next;
       }
       if(del->next != NULL)
       {
         del->next->prev = del->prev;
       }
       if(del->prev != NULL)
       {
         del->prev->next = del->next;
       }
       free(del);
       return;

}

int Menu()
{
  int c;

  printf("\n*** M E N U ***\n"
     "1 - New Node\n"
     "2 - View List\n"
   "3 - Delete\n"
   "0 - Exit\n"
  "\n>> ");
  scanf(" %d", &c);

  return c;
}

int main()
{
  int c;
  struct Test test, del;
  Node list = NULL;

  do {
    c = Menu();

    switch (c)
    {
      case 1: ReadStructure(&test);
              NewNode(test, &list); break;
      case 2: ViewList(list); break;
      case 3: Delete(&list, del); break;
      default: c = 0;
    }

  } while (c != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

del value is NULL, but you reference it when you delete.
What you need is to search a node in the list for the givent id and then delete it.

Comment: I already know that, but how do i delete it without the pointer passed to function Delete() and without touching the algorithm?